# show different forms based on radio button selection is not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I have a page to edit the administrators of a post.

In this page there are some radio buttons. Each radio button corresponds to a administrator of a post. When a radio button is selected the details of that administrator are populated in the form fields.

When the user accesses this edit administrators of a post page no radio button should be checked by default, so I don't have the "checked" property in the radio buttons.

In this page I want to have 2 forms, a form for update and a form to store administrators.

So, for example when the user acesses this page there are for example 3 radio buttons: John, Jake, Create new admin. If the radio button that corresponds to the user John is selected the update form should appear with the form fields populated with the John admin details, the same for the Jake amdin. If the "Create new admin" radio button
is selected it should appear the store form with the form fields reset.

The issue is when the user acesses this edit administrators of a post page no radio button is appearing, so its not possible to select any radio button and so no form appears. Do you know how to organize this two forms properly so that each form appears when the correspondent radio button is selected?

**// update form**

```
<form id="update_admins" method="post" class="clearfix"
              action="{{route('admins.update', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" >
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
                    <label for="admins">Post admins</label>

                    @foreach($administrators as $admin)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $admin->id }}" id="{{$admin->id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                {{$admin->name}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach

                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="update_admin"
                               value="update_admin">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                            Create new admin
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ $admin->name }}" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <!-- ...the other form fields -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right" value="Update admin"/>
        </form>
```

**// store form**

```
<form id="create_admins" method="post" class="clearfix"
              action="{{route('admins.store', ['post_id' => $post->id])}}" >
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col col-lg-6">
                    <label for="admins">Post admins</label>

                    @foreach($administrators as $admin)
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input radio" type="radio" name="radiobutton" value="{{ $admin->id }}" id="{{$admin->id}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                                {{$admin->name}}
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach

                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input autocomplete="off" class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="radiobutton" id="store_admin"
                               value="store_admin">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                            Create new admin
                        </label>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input autocomplete="off" type="text" required class="form-control" value="{{ old('name') }}" name="name" id="name">
            </div>
            <!-- ...the other form fields -->
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn float-right" value="Store admin"/>
        </form>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            // receive array with administrators details from the AdministratorController
            var admins = {!!  $administrators !!}

            $("#create_admins").hide();
            $("#update_admins").hide();

            $("input[name='radiobutton']").click(function() {
                let id = $(this).attr("id");

                if (id == "store_admin") {

                    $("input[name='name']").val("");
                } else {
                    let data = admins.find(e => e.id == id) || {
                        name: "",
                            ...
                    };

                    $("input[name='name']").val(data.name);
                    ...
                }
            });

            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recognize the forms by controller action

```
@if(\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod()  == 'create')
    //show create form
@else
   //show edit form
@endif
```